# Bootstrap Popover shouldn't get destroyed every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have two inputs (checkboxes) inside my popover.
The problem is, that I can't get the data out of them because the popovers apperas in the DOM when I click a button, at the time I click it again it gets removed. I guess the problem is that javascript already initialized from the beginning and so my script doesn't recognize the inputs.

So you can say, in general I want to achieve two inputs in a popover, which gets displayed on button click. The data of the inputs(checked or not checked) should be processed in either AngularJS or jQuery.

I'm using bootstrap, jQuery and AngularJS for my project.

I would appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the popover event to trigger your function to get the data from the checkbox. ive made an example n posted it on jsfiddle, im not sure if this is what your looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/rtn5y6qf/2/

html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="<div class='checkbox-div'><input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='Bike'>I have a bike<br><input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='Car'>I have a car</div>">Popover on Right</button>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('button').popover({
    html: true
  });
});

$(document).on('shown.bs.popover', 'button', function (t, v) {
  $('.checkbox-div').find('input').each(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```